# What happened to the web sockets and when will they be back?

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, web-sockets

For some good hours now, there is no web sockets connection in Stack Exchange sites i.e. no live updates of question lists, new answers, inbox items, notifications etc.

What happened to the web sockets and when can we expect to see them back in their full glory?

Worth to mention, they are enabled only on the main https://stackexchange.com/ portal so things like the [Realtime Questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) work fine. It's disabled (not even sending a request) on the sites themselves.

Comment: My realtime tab is still working just fine

Comment: @JanDvorak true, updated the question.

Comment: From [Nick's answer yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224991/unable-to-ask-a-question-on-stack-overflow/224995#224995) - "web sockets blowing past 260,000 simultaneous connections (which exceeds some linux networking limits)". Obviously, doesn't say when it'll be back so a dev would have to answer that. But that could explain where they went.

Comment: SO seems to have got them back up.

Comment: @StevenV true, but I assumed they were back up and stable when the rest of the site was stable.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau right! Couldn't help to notice it changed from NY to QA though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web sockets are back online and working as before.

Thank you anonymous developer who fixed this! :)