# Display of the community wiki correct?

Tags: support, design, community-wiki

Is the display of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225169/what-happened-to-the-web-sockets-and-when-will-they-be-back) community wiki correct. I think the grey background should not be there.

Or is this cause Shadow Wizard is the owner of the post and all the occurrences of his names are highlighted in that way?

[image]

Comment: May be it shows it only on answers given by the OP?

Comment: Ohh! I found that this is already given in [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22184/187824). But for non-community wiki answers. So same applies to CW answers as well.

Comment: Same as comment. You can see if OP posted a comment then user name will be displayed with gray background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a CW answer to your own post, somewhere deep in the nesting the `td` element that holds the 'community wiki' text is given the css class `post-signature owner`.

If you're not the asker of the question, it's being given `post-signature`.

```
.post-signature {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 175px;
    height: 58px;
}

.owner {
    background-color: #deedff; // striked through
    background-color: rgba(222, 237, 255, 0.4); // striked through
    background-color: #e0eaf1;
}
```

This would indicate to me that this behaviour is by-design.

Tested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972478/socket-is-only-catching-outgoing-packets-not-incoming-ones/22055734#22055734) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303704/why-it-is-advisable-to-wrap-bufferreader-around-inputstreamreader/22303763#22303763).

Comment: Ok, i think that will answer my question. It looked somehow misplaced.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225412/187824). As I [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225411/display-of-the-community-wiki-correct/225413#comment736549_225411) the grey background indicates that the answer is given by the OP. It doesn't show that background if the answer is given by other users. See this:

> [image]

So this is by design.

Comment: Oh, so you are the mysterious tester! The iOS app store the comments even after you delete them, but won't show who is their author. :)